# How to sign up user to AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool and get the JWT tokens back?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

How to sign up a user to AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool and get the JWT tokens back?

I got Facebook token from facebook registration. Then how can I register user in the User pool with based on that token?

I need to get JWT tokens in responce after that to use them in my own backend.

Struggling with it a week already..

Answer (score 0):

Recognize authentication is a two step process. First, your app must authenticate with  Facebook to receive a JWT, it seems that you have done this successfully. Second, this JWT is exchanged for IAM credentials that will be used for API calls.

Authentication Flow:

1. App authenticates with Identity provider using the SDK for that identity provider. In response, the Identity provider sends a JWT that will be cached by the app.
2. App uses cached JWT to authenticate with AWS. If the Identity provider is configured in AWS, in response, AWS sends IAM credentials with the permissions granted to that identity provider.
3. IAM credentials are used to make calls to other AWS resources specified in the Policy

This [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html) goes into more detail for these steps in regarding Facebook.

The AWS Amplify Library has support for iOS. I would recommend using this library to [handle Authentication against Facebook Federated Identities](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#facebook-login-in-your-mobile-app).

You do not necessarily need a user pool managed in Cognito, as the user pool function is managed by Facebook.

Comment: thanks, I suppose I understand how it works, but ios sdk does not work properly I think. Could u send me some working sample in ObjC or SWIFT with getting Cognito Access Token after registering as a Facebook user? I struggled with this a week already..

Comment: I would recommend using the AWS Amplify Library for iOs - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#facebook-login-in-your-mobile-app This may be able to help